# Why is the model I am trying to use not working?

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

I keep getting an error when I enter this code. I even returned to the original csv, replaced the spaces in the headings with underscores (ex: "Property_Damage"),and the code still did not work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I've tried eliminating the spaces in my headings.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, instead, have your code in the description of your question

Comment: The name shown in your View tab (iihs_data) is different from the name you are calling your line of code (IIHS).

Comment: Good call by Phil.  To OP Hanna, to extend Phil's observation, note that R is case sensitive.  E.g. IIHS_Data != iihs_data.